# Jquery Function conflicts with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

in functions.php of my wordpress site i have this code to call jquery:

```
    function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

However, this code conflicts with this jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#menu > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-55px'  /* para não elevar muito o separador*/
                }, 300);
            $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'-10px'
                }, 400);
        },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-130px'  /* para baixar o separador para o sitio original*/
                }, 300);
            $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'50px'
                }, 400);
        }
    );
});
```

i'm sure this is the problem because if i call http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js directly in the head of the page the plugin works. I'm triying to avoid using jquery.noConflict to avoid problems with other jquery plugins on the same page.

Any hint?

Comment: weird...I've always done it like that and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading the script?

If it's in the footer, try this:

```
    (function($) {
    $('#menu > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-55px'  /* para não elevar muito o separador*/
                }, 300);
            $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'-10px'
                }, 400);
        },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-130px'  /* para baixar o separador para o sitio original*/
                }, 300);
            $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'50px'
                }, 400);
        }
    );
})( jQuery );
```

If it's in the header, try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {  
    $('#menu > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-55px'  /* para não elevar muito o separador*/
                }, 300);
            $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'-10px'
                }, 400);
        },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('a',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'bottom':'-130px'  /* para baixar o separador para o sitio original*/
                }, 300);
            $('i',$this).stop(true,true).animate({
                    'top':'50px'
                }, 400);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: it's in the header but didn't work.
i ended calling the jquerycorefile directly in the page and calling the enqueue_script to the plugins and this way is working.

Answer (score 0):

Glad that it worked for you, but you are way better off using wp_enqueue.

Check out this article http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/

You can also try replacing the "$" selectors with "jQuery". Wordpress has a number of libraries included as a part of core and the $ is used for more then just jQuery.

Comment: During my search i ended in that page too. Well, for now i will mantain this code. But if i have problems that suggestion will be the first i will try. Thanks for the help.